# IIS Rewrite based on query string value

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, routes

I am new to IIS Rewrite, Need someone to assist me,

I am in a scenario to redirect to another domain based on querystring value.

**Ex:**

Request:

[http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1000&stdName="Test"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1000&stdName=%22Test%22)

[http://localhost:50752/api/Values?stdId=1001&stdName="Test1"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1001&stdName=%22Test1%22)

[http://localhost:50753/api/Values?stdId=1002&stdName="Test2"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1002&stdName=%22Test2%22)

[http://localhost:50754/api/Values?stdId=1004&stdName="Test4"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1003&stdName=%22Test3%22)

I just need to validate the **query string** and redirect the request to **different domain** based on **stdId** value

if **stdId=1000** request has to be redirected to [http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1000&stdName="Test"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1000&stdName=%22Test%22)

if **stdId=1001** request has to be redirected to
[http://localhost:50752/api/Values?stdId=1001&stdName="Test1"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1001&stdName=%22Test1%22)

if **stdId=1002** request has to be redirected to
[http://localhost:50753/api/Values?stdId=1002&stdName="Test1"](http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1001&stdName=%22Test1%22)

etc..,

**Code what i have tried:**

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to another service" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>                
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" negate="false" pattern="(stdId=1000)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:50762/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below rule to redirect url based on query string:

```
<rule name="querystring redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="stdId=1000" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:50743/api/Values?stdId=1000&amp;stdName=&quot;Test&quot;" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Create a rule for every URL query string parameter.
Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: i dont want to hard code stdName it should be passed from original request

Comment: You could modify condition as <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="stdId=1000&amp;stdName=&quot;(.*)&quot;" />
</conditions>